# Stop a thread executing in background and then return the result

Tags: java, multithreading

I call a java file that performs background operations. Due to a thread that is executing on the background (in another java file) I cannot return the result to the jsp page.  It is known that return and system.exit(0) cannot be used at the same time. Is there anyway to stop the thread in the visible java file and return the result.

Answer (score 1):

You could benefit from formulating your question more carefully. There are no such thing as 'thread executing in another Java file' so it's not clear what do you mean exactly.

There is not simple/safe way in Java to terminate arbitrary Thread. Usually the easiest would be to use [ExecutorService](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html), submit your job to it and hold on on returned [Future](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html) object which you could use to get result later or to cancel job execution. You also could shutdown ExecutorService without waiting for job(s) to complete if you wish to do so. Obviously your jobs should be written with cancellation in mind in such case, so there are no undesired side effects.

Answer (score 0):

If you wrap the thread in a try {...} catch (InterruptedException ex) { ... } block you can use the Thread.interrupt() method ([http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#interrupt()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#interrupt%28%29)). This will send the thread to the interrupt handler where you can tidy up anything you need to before returning the result.

I think you will need to have somewhere in your run loop where you check thread.isInterrupted() and if so break out of the loop to the interrupt handler as there are times when calling .interrupt() from the main program won't cause the thread to jump to the interrupt handler. All the details on this are on the page I linked to earlier.

Answer (score 0):

Your intent is not very clear, but you might want to take a look at the Java `Future` and `ScheduledFuture` interfaces and the multi-threading classes that use them.